# Is it possible to have UUID as part of URL?

Tags: java, rest, url, uri, uuid

I designing an restful APIs for People resource. I have UUID as ID for person resource.  When i access the following URL it works fine

`http://localhost:8080/peoples/`

returns

```
"peoples": [
  {
    "name": "Miss. Lina Thomas",
    "sex": "female",
    "age": 23,
    "_links": {
      "self": 
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/peoples/30303864-3633-3237-2d63-6635322d3438"
    },
    "people": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/peoples/30303864-3633-3237-2d63-6635322d3438"
    }
  }
]
```

But if i want to pass UUID as part of URL, call is not made. Browser returns error `No webpage was found for the web address`

`http://localhost:8080/peoples/49dc24bd-906d-4497-bcfc-ecc8c309ecfc`

Is it possible to pass UUID as part of restful URL?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Your server need to be implemented to accept it though. It is clearly not the case here.